Are questions about "being a quant" in scope?
The original Stack Overflow is dedicated to actual programming questions, whereas questions about "being a programmer" are meant for Programmers. However, since I do not foresee this site growing to the point where we could have two independent sites like for programming, I wonder if it would be OK to ask questions about the specifics of working in quantitative finance?
The specific question I have in mind is 

What benefits are there to employing agile software development methodologies for quants?


Generally, yes; unless the site gets enormous (ala Stack Overflow), there is no need to break out "soft" career related questions into another site.
Joel and I always intended for career questions to be on-topic, but they ended up at #6 or #7 in the voting, so they are definitely less desirable than the strong technical questions:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/a-question-about-questions/
